# Корневая папка wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! Перенес wordpress на другой хостинг и теперь не могу загружать файлы (изображения, плагины ставить и т. д.) ошибку выдает [image] хотя в базе поменял путь до корневой папки...что делать? неужели заново ставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На новом хостинге некоторым папкам необходимо назначить права, дружище, поставь на весь WP 777, заработает 100%.